# Best practice to add an Application wide Header View in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Let's say my main view controller will be a tab bar with misc sub view controllers (i.e the first will be navigation controller, the second will a subclass of uiviewcontroller, etc)

Now I want to add a static header view (will contain at least a logo uiimageview like websites)

so what is the best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Just a cautionary note, quoting the HIG: "Avoid taking space away from the content people care about. For example, displaying a second, persistent bar at the top of the screen that does nothing but display branding assets means that there’s less room for content. Consider other, less intrusive ways to display pervasive branding, such as subtly customizing the background of a screen."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As Mark Adams explains in the comments, below, this is *not* a good strategy.  I'll leave it as an note on what not to do.

---

"Best practice" is a dicey term, but what immediately comes to mind for me is to make your `UITabBarController` the root and only view controller of a parent `UINavigationController`.  Then you can put whatever logo `UIImageView` you like in the navigation bar.

Comment: `UITabBarController` isn't meant to be used in that way. The class reference for it states that a tab bar controller is only supposed to be installed in an instance of `UIWindow`. Embedding a tab bar controller in another view controller can lead to some very strange layout behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going for a `UINavigationBar` style, then I would recommend subclassing UIView and creating your custom view and using a simple implementation and offset value to add it to each of your `UIViewControllers`. Its a hassle, but it avoids having to throw on unnecessary `UINavigationControllers` to your project.

As for best practice, you should alway keep the `UITabBarController` as the root of your window, rather than having a `UINavigationController` with a `UITabBarController` as a root.

Also, I do appreciate the other poster's name.